# How to switch applications using Cmd+Tab when inside VirtualBox without using Host key?

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox, shortcut

When inside VirtualBox in order to switch to an OSX app, I first press Host key which is Right Option, then I press Cmd+Tab.

I wonder if there is some trick to eliminate pressing Host key before Cmd+Tab?